# How to install object_manipulation package for ros hydro on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ros, object-manipulation, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install object_manipulation package for ros hydro (which I installed from source) on ubuntu 13.10.  To do that I downloaded the source of package from github link and tried to run following command in the downloaded folder:

sudo /opt/ros/hydro/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install --install-space /opt/ros/hydro

However I am getting following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/hydro/bin/catkin_make_isolated", line 12, in 
from catkin.builder import build_workspace_isolated
ImportError: No module named catkin.builder

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/136771/how-to-install-object_manipulation-package-for-ros-hydro-on-ubuntu-13.10/) by [Alice](https://answers.ros.org/users/12911/alice/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did source the bash file before running catkin_make_isolated.

Update: I realized when I use sudo, previous source command does not have any effect. Therefore I switched to root. Issued the source command and then used
catkin_make_isolated --install --install-space /opt/ros/hydro . But now I am getting following error:
Could not find source space : None

I get the same error when I install it as a non root user without using sudo by changing the path to a local path in home folder.

---

Originally posted by [Alice](https://answers.ros.org/users/12911/alice/) with karma: 16 on 2014-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0